# Bullet simulation stops after windows inactivate

Tags: bullet-physics

I am having trouble when inactivating window (event resizing); all the contents get rendered and input works. Even the physics work but the btDiscreteDynamicsWorld stepSimulation function does not get called. I am using SFML for window and clock. If any more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Yes, what have you tried to do to fix it? If a line of code is not being called, you should be stepping through the code to find out why.

Comment: every function is being called. Event the step function gets called. Its something inside the stepSimulation function. I can't even find anything about this anywhere in the internet.

Comment: its weird because when the simulation starts, there is not problem with doing other work.